# Distributive law for subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I believe that for subgroups $H,K,L\le G$ distributivity does not apply, but could someone give an example to illustrate this:
$$
\langle H\cup K\rangle\cap L\neq\langle (H\cap L)\cup (K\cap L)\rangle
$$

Apparently with subgroups $n\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ equality is fulfilled.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Correct, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G = S_3$, and let $H$ and $L$ be generated by distinct $2$-cycles and $K$ be generated by a $3$-cycle. Then $\langle H \cup K\rangle \cap L = G \cap L = L$, whereas $\langle (H \cap L) \cup (K \cap L)\rangle = \langle 1 \cup 1\rangle = 1$.

Comment: Thanks! Bungo for your solution.

Comment: @felipeuni My pleasure. By the way, I just noticed that the same argument works if $H$, $K$, and $L$ are all distinct $2$-cycles in $S_3$, e.g. $H = (12)$, $K=(23)$, $L=(13)$.